# How do i replace the fourth row of values in a dataframe with a corresponding vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a set of values

```
 col1|col2|col3|col4
    5   10   15   20
    2    4    6    8
    3    6    9   12
    4    3    7   15
```

I would like to replace row 4 with a vector

```
 c(4,8,12,16)
```

I would like to inset the vector in column 4 and replace the original values. I tried this script.

```
df[[4]]<- vector_name
```

I expect the result

```
  col1|col2|col3|col4
    5   10   15   20
    2    4    6    8
    3    6    9   12
    4    8   12   16
```

Comment: `df[4,]<- c(4,8,12,16)`

Comment: Some explanation: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(df1, cbind(nrow(df1), seq_along(df1)), v1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(5L, 2L, 3L, 4L), col2 = c(10L, 4L, 6L, 
3L), col3 = c(15L, 6L, 9L, 7L), col4 = c(20L, 8L, 12L, 15L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

v1 <- c(4, 8, 12, 16)
```